# Why is rowsAffected not returning an integer

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, sqlite

I'm calling the executeSql statement for SQLite on iOS. I'm using the success [and error] callback methods so that I can confirm my number of records affected count.

When it comes back, it's got the 3 variables defined correctly, but when I try and do an "if" check on the rowsAffected, it's not working because it thinks it's an object.

This is in an Angular service...

Here's my code:

```
    $DBService.ExecuteQuery(script, params,
        function (insertId, rowsAffected, rows) {
            window.logger.logIt("rowsAffected: " + rowsAffected.toString());

            if (rowsAffected !== 1) {
                deferred.reject("Failed to update record. Query did not return 1 record affected.");
            } else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            deferred.reject("Failed to update record. " + error.message);
        }
    );
```

When I break in my debugger and hover over the rowsAffected variable, it displays it as if it's a property of a class, where it shows: insertId, rowsAffected = 1, and rows. Those are the 3 parameters in the success callback. Why is it showing all 3 when I'm just hovering over the rowsAffected? Also, when I write to my console window (window.logger.logIt()), it displays it as [object object]. Again, that tells me it thinks it's a class, instead of the property of the class (or just a variable in my class).

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: By the way, I cheated and changed my code to say if (rowsAffected.rowsAffected !== 1) and that works, but it does not explain WHY.

Comment: What makes you think it is not an object indeed ?

Comment: Just from going by the documentation saying that it's returning 3 parameters, insertId, rowsAffected, and rows. Where the first two are ints, and the third is an array of the rows affected. http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs clearly state:

> The executeSql() method invokes its callback with a **SQLResultSet object** as an argument.

So the argument passed to the callback is **an object** with three specified properties. 
Always trust the DevTools.

So, it should be more like:

```
$DBService.ExecuteQuery(script, params,
    function (resultSetObj) {
        ...
        if (resultSetObj.rowsAffected !== 1) {
            ...
```